# generate sequence in impala sql

Tags: sql, impala

I'd like to generate in sql some rows of fake data with a sequence of integer (given a max number).
The result should be something like that

```
1
2
3
4
5
...
10
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easier way to generate series but its not too difficult either.
You need to use a large table with lots of rows for this.

```
SELECT seq FROM (
SELECT
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY 'test' ORDER BY 'test') as seq
FROM 
    large_table
)rs
WHERE seq <= 100
```

here
`row_number()` - is used to generate row number for each row in large table.
`where` - is used to limit rows to 100. You can change this to any number.

Comment: And a `large_table` may be generated in place using `values` and a cross join as much times as required.

Comment: thanks Koushik Roy. It was my plan B. I was looking for something more elegant.

Comment: astentx, can you elaborate better? I'm curious

Comment: so sorry, this is most elegant way i can present :) @astentx's solution doesnt seems to be elegant if you need higher sequence.

Comment: @LucaMonno There's no any solution in my comment and the answer provided is the only way to generate sequential number in Impala due to absence of table functions and recursive subqueries. My comment was about obtaining a large enough table: `values` and `cross join` provide an ability to generate as much rows as needed exponentially with no physical reads. Then the above approach should be used to limit the number of result sequence values. See an example on Postgres [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wSzwyDS_), which works in Impala also